# Constructing an appropriate null hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, histogram, scipy, numpy

I have a collection of 20 2D surfaces embedded in 3D. The mean curvature of each surface has been sampled.

The number of samples per surface varies from ~700,000 to ~20,000,000. The choice of sampling number is highly dependent on the underying geometry & not a parameter I have any control over due to experimental conatraints.

I have collected the data from each surface into histograms & used Sturge's rule for the number of bins. I then checked for normal distributions, none of them follow a normal distribution. But one thing they do all have in common is that there is a peak count in the bin that contains a value of 0. In fact in all cases 25% to 30% of all samples are contained within this bin. The bin width's in every case fall within acceptable ranges from an experimental point of view.

I am hypothesising that the surfaces prefer (have a tendancy?) to be around the zero mean curvature mark.

And this is where my knowledge of statistics comes to an end.

Am I correct in thinking that I can do a t-test against another set of data that represents data from a null hypothesis?

I'm guessing that my null hypothesis would be that the surfaces do in fact tend towards having a mean curvature of 0

If so how would I go about constructing such a data set? Would it be random samples from an approriate interval with normal distribution centred at 0?

Thanks for any help. I am doing all analysis in Python using Numpy & Scipy